# insert sub-id column into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
ID  TYPE    ESC END
TRL EC1 MISL1123    36
TRL EC2 XISL1124    57
LBL EC1 CARB24  20
LBL EC1 AARB70  96
LBL EC2 MUT23   79
```

I want to insert a column of sequential sub-ids (Column "SEQUENCE") into the dataframe to account for multiple enteries in column "ID":

```
ID  TYPE    SEQUENCE    ESC END
TRL EC1 seq0    MISL1123    36
TRL EC2 seq1    XISL1124    57
LBL EC1 seq0    CARB24  20
LBL EC1 seq1    AARB70  96
LBL EC2 seq2    MUT23   79
```

Here's my attempt that didn't work:

```
df['SEQUENCE']=df.groupby(df['ID', 'TYPE']).cumsum().astype(int))
```

What changes can I make to get this code to work? Thanks

Comment: cumcount is what you need which will create a count without modifying your index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this accomplish what you needed?

```
df['Sequence'] = 'seq' + df.groupby('ID').cumcount().astype(str)
```

Comment: Awesome! Exacly what I wanted. Thanks for your help @ArchAngelPwn